# vpn privacy issue

Tags: networking, vpn

i recently start working for this large company. i work remotely and connect via vpn. i notice my user folder(C:\Users\a_user) and its content is visible on the network(i find out what my ip is among the network and put that in explorer). my user folder is not shared. how do i prevent this?

Comment: Sorry, but what?  This probably doesn't belong on serverfault.  Anyway, you might provide more details about how you accessed your computer.

Comment: We definitely need more details: What do you mean by visible on the network? On what machine? is it your local files? are you logging into another machine through the VPN? ...

Comment: Ok, I thought we had the discussion about moving questions to SU when it's pretty obviously not a complete question. Who voted to move?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn off file and printer sharing on your computer (unless your company policy requires that it be enabled).

The odds of an employee connecting to your machine and looking at your files is slim.  As it is a company computer you shouldn't be storing anything on the computer which isn't the companies.

If it isn't a company machine, and it isn't on the domain then other users won't have access to your computer because they won't have a login on your computer so you shouldn't have a problem.  You can see them from your computer because you have an account on your own machine.

Comment: i should probably set the password

Comment: Although the details aren't there, it sounds like he's using Windows 7, which "shares" the User folders automatically.  However, nothing can be accessed by other users unless permissions are explicitly set.  You can see all of the contents because you have the access, but other users can't unless you actually gave them file or folder read permissions.